# Is there a way to use VSE to render faster?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I am a beginner Blender user (Probably always will be), and I sometimes use blender for video editing. I was wondering if there is a way to decrese your time, cause I use the Replay mod to record at 2596x1440p60 and it takes 15 mins to an hour to render a 1 ind video just to add sound. Is there a way to simply merge sound and video without rendering for hours?
Thanks. Btw I'm on a Mac yosemite

Comment: In my opinion,  you'll get better performance using  a dedicated video editing app that is optimized to use GPU... like Davinci Resolve, Premiere or Final Cut pro...

Comment: You search for a Muxing Software like AviDemux which can help you add an audio track without reencoding.